# IISExpress based app doesn't get IP based requests

Tags: iis-express, netsh

I seemingly applied every recommendation available on net. Yet without results.
My environment:

- Windows 10 Enterprise @ VM (possibly WMware)
- VS Prof 2017 ver 15.5.2
- .NET 4.5 Web application
- IISExpress with ProjectURL http://localhost:8080 (Created virtual directory)

Following recommendations I did following:

1. Run as Admin:  netsh http add urlacl url=http://:8080/ user=everyone
2. Added element binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:8080:*" / in C:\Users\myself\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config
3. In Windows Firewall add Inbound Rules: %ProgramFiles%\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe

What I get:

1. When debugging IISExress-based application from Visual I get to breakpoints by getting http://localhost:8080/myresource from browser but http://myip:8080/myresource (from the same machine!!!) doesn't get me to breakpoint
2. Inspecting C:\Users\myself\Documents\IISExpress\TraceLogFiles\WebSite1 reveals no trace to the latest request.
3. Running from IISExpress from Admin/Cmd as "c:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe" /path:"C:\myapp.Web" /port:8080 /trace:e    is also unsuccessful. BTW, it starts with suspicious "Successfully registered URL "http://localhost:8080/"". Where is my ip??!!!

Comment: If you don't sync the project file with your config file, VS won't behave as you like, https://blog.lextudio.com/jexus-manager-secrets-behind-visual-studio-iis-express-integration-834f88c8e8b The command line to run IIS Express is also wrong if you want it not to use localhost. Read IIS Express command line documentation again please.

Comment: That blog describes (solution folder)\.vs\config\applicationHost.config files. I have only Users\myself\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config. Perhaps, it's the same (VS compatibility issue. Mine one is 2017). Regarding content of applicationhost.config the blog describes the 2nd instance of "site" element which is meaningful. My config has only the default one "WebSite1". Unfortunately, it doesn't solve my problem. That far I use standalone localhost proxy. Regards,

Comment: The `.vs` folder is hidden by default.